# Azure AI Video Indexer Left and Right arrows does not work anymore

Tags: arrow-keys, azure-video-indexer

I used to control the playback with my keyboard arrow keys but they are not working anymore.

I couldn't find any setting to make it enable again. Also the space key doesn't work for pausing the videos. I tried several browsers but it didn't word. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: The questions you answer tend to be about MS Azure configuration, pricing, infrastructure, and other cloud-related issues, instead of being practical programming problems. StackOverflow is meant to discuss only programming questions. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
for more details. Please post your non-programming question on other platforms such as [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)
, and [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/tags/133/azure)
for immediate help. Thanks!